# Firebase Presence Detection not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried this code in my app, but I never get a callback for any network change.

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please add your JSON structure?

Comment: The above same code works fine for me. I have added this in onCreate() method.

Comment: @AritraRoy have you found a solution to this problem ? I'm stuck with the same issue. Thanks

Comment: It seems to work perfectly for me now. I have't changed any code. May be the latest SDK fixed some problems. What SDK version are you using?